# Merge multiple rows into 1 in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

My search-fu has failed me, but I THINK i'm on the right track with the MERGE statement.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
P_K,Col_1,Col2,Col3
1,word,null,null
1,null,number,null
1,null,null,3
```

I want the result of my statement to look like this:

```
P_K,Col_1,Col_2,Col_3
1,word,number,3
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to modify the data in the table (so that a table that starts with 3 rows ends up having just 1 row)?  Or are you trying to combine the data in a query (so that the table has the same 3 rows but the query only returns 1 row)?

Comment: Both paradigms could be useful, but my current efforts using MERGE it seems the intent of that keyword is to create a new table from an existing old one. As a matter of practicality, it doesnt matter. Whichever is easiest.

Comment: Not really.  `MERGE` is a useful way of combining `insert`, `update`, and `delete` operations in a single statement.  It has nothing to do with creating new tables-- that's done with a `CREATE TABLE` statement.  Are you saying that you are asking two questions-- one on how to combine the three rows in the table into one row in the table and one on how to write a query that leaves three rows in the table and produces a single row of output?

Comment: I see. Lets assume for the moment that i want to compress the rows that currently exist. So that my example becomes true given that I want to modify the existing table to get the desired result.

Comment: Curveball: I cannot simply use MAX, as the fields may be varchar.
*edit*
So my initial table example was incorrect.

Comment: What does the data type have to do with the aggregate function?  If, as in your example, there is only one non-NULL value per column per `p_k` value, `max` will give you that value whether the columns are numbers, strings, dates, etc.

Comment: Thank you, Justin Cave. I dont know why I was hung up on MAX() not working on non-numeric fields. It looks like MAX is going to work!

Comment: @Justin I see you are new to Stackoverflow and this is your first question.  When someone has answered your question you can click the hollow checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as the accepted answer.  You do not have messaging turned on, so I had to send this as a comment.  I will delete this comment when/if you mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a query that returns one row of data, simple aggregation should work

```
SELECT t.p_k,
       max( t.col_1 ) col_1,
       max( t.col_2 ) col_2,
       max( t.col_3 ) col_3
  FROM table_name t
 GROUP BY t.p_k
```

Answer (score 1):

You are short on a few details to really give you a good answer, but here is one way to do it with the very small set of data you have provided.

```
select x.P_K
      ,(select a.col_1 from t a where a.p_k = x.p_k and a.col_1 not NULL) as col_1
      ,(select b.col_2 from t b where b.p_k = x.p_k and b.col_2 not NULL) as col_2
      ,(select c.col_3 from t c where c.p_k = x.p_k and c.col_3 not NULL) as col_3
  from t x
 group by x.P_K
```

Another way might be like this:

```
select x.P_K
      ,MAX(x.col_1) as col_1
      ,MAX(x.col_2) as col_2
      ,MAX(x.col_3) as col_3
  from t x
 group by x.P_K
```

The one you use will depend on the edge cases in your data.

If you want to tolerate more than one row for each of the col_N, then you use MAX.  If you want the select to fail if there is more than one row for each of the col_N, then use the subselect technique.

By fail I mean the database engine will report an error that says more than one row returned in a context where only one row is allowed.  Depending on what you are doing, you may want to know about data that does not fit the pattern.

The MAX() technique will run faster.